# Custom Cron job is not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-cron

Custom Cron job is not working in Magento 2 when the schedule set like below:

```
<schedule>30 17 * * 0</schedule>
```

Only working when `<schedule>* * * * *</schedule>` in magento 2.2.5

Comment: It will only be fired on sunday.. did you notice that?

Comment: yes but entry not found in cron schedule table

Comment: Did you set magento2 cron properly? Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: The most recent entries would be there. It might be deleted I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set any cron schedule of next half an hour and check entry in cron_schedule table. It would be available there when you run below command:

> php bin/magento cron:run

I hope it will help you out.